# iOS push notification action in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with push notification. I want to call some method when someone taps on a notification.
When the app isn't running it's simple (`application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions call method`). But when the app is running in the background, I have to call method after tap, not after receive notification (`didReceiveRemoteNotification`).

I don't know how to do this.

Is there some method to check if a notification was tapped when the app is in the background?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to call method after tap"? Are you asking to how to show a `UIAlertView`?

Comment: No. Some custom method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if (launchOptions)
    { //launchOptions is not nil

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        userInfoDic = userInfo;

        if (apsInfo)
        { //apsInfo is not nil
            [self performSelector:@selector(postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC)
                       withObject:nil
                       afterDelay:1];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}



-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *) userInfo

    {
               UIApplicationState state = [app applicationState];

        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground)
        {
             [self postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC];
        }

        else
        {
         ...
        }
    }

-(void)postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"recievePush" object:userInfoDic];
}
```

Comment: Edit answer: state == UIApplicationStateBackground

Comment: It's still answer that call method each time when push will be recieved.

Comment: when the app is running in the background, you got message in notifications, and when you tap it - my method start. What wrong? Try it.

Comment: I have tried something like this. didReceive method is calling ech time when app get push (not after tap).

Comment: add code 4 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and when app in background, all work like you need.